# React Webpack not rebuilding when edited file outside docker container (on mac)

Tags: macos, reactjs, docker, webpack, create-react-app

I've used create-react-app to create a react app inside a docker container.
When I edit App.js inside the container, the app automatically gets rebuilt and the browser reloads.
But when I edit a file *outside* the container (on the host) it doesn't get rebuilt.

Is this is a webpack/watch problem - but maybe also has something to do with running docker on a mac?
Any help would be appreciated.

I assume this sort of thing is quite normal for a developer setup (ie - using docker to create your build environment but using a mount for the actual code).

[Here](https://github.com/roocell/fullstack_react_nodejs_in_docker) is a Github repo with what I'm using.

Comment: maybe you mounted incorrectly the volume to match host/container file. When you edit the file (host), have you checked that the container file also changes?

Comment: yes. a write to the file in either the container or the host and the changes are reflected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out myself.
It was webpack configuration that was prevented an edit from outside the container to trigger a rebuild and restart.
The trick being (and apparently this is a legacy option)

```
watchOptions {
  poll: 100
}
```

NOTE: using poll:1000 resulted in it only refreshing every other edit. Using 100 works every edit. not sure why.

So for my backend API I am running node/expressjs. Here I needed to install and run webpack and nodemon. (nodemon needed the -L option to work while editing outside of the container).

My frontend is created using create-react-app where none of the webpack configuration is exposed. I had to run

```
npm run eject
```

to expose the webpack configuration (which I edited the config/webpackDevServer.config.js file).

Now, using eject is frowned upon because "you can't go back"...but since I'm using a docker container and using create-react-app/eject when I build the container - I have effectively saved myself from this undesirable situation. (although I may have to fix my docker file if anything changes on me).

All these edits can be found in my docker files here
https://github.com/roocell/fullstack_react_nodejs_in_docker

Answer (score 13):

In my case enabling this environment variable resolved it:

```
CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

Just this setting, no installation was necessary. The [Chokidar docs](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) state that it helps to watch files over a network. As it seems, this also can be helpful for docker volumes.

**PS:** The CPU load was quite high, so I sadly also had to reduce the interval of checks by setting `CHOKIDAR_INTERVAL=1000`.

---

You can set this variable in the `docker-compose.yml` file …

```
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

… or in a `Dockerfile` …

```
ENV CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

… or via command line by something like:

```
docker run -e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true my-app
```

Answer (score 1):

You should link your host's folder containing your application files to the container using [Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume). Even better would be to use [Docker-Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) since you're using multiple containers.

Docker containers are purely meant to run code, not edit it. You really shouldn't be using an editor inside of a container.

I do think however that your current application structure is incorrect. Your API should provide data that your frontend retrieves and displays. Currently your backend code only functions as a router for your frontend application, but instead you should use a [client-side router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router) and build a RESTFUL JSON-sending API. Then from your clientside javascript you can do `fetch` calls to your API, which should `res.send` some JSON.

Comment: Definitely not intending to edit code inside the container - want to mount a host directory for development purposes. Will using a Volume actually fix my problem? I'll try it.

I do intend to use a client-side router and have the backend spit out JSON - just haven't gotten that far yet. Thanks for the link to the npm - didn't know about it.

Comment: That's good to hear. You are already using Volumes in your `docker run` command, but instead of running two long commands every time you can use Docker-Compose as I suggested.
I don't see a package.json file in your git repo, could you push it? We need to determine what kind of watcher you use (something like nodemon/pm2 or even some webpack scripts)

Comment: I've pushed again. the watcher is whatever react uses - presumably webpack i believe. I also have a package.json for my backend (which is an expressjs app and uses webpack/nodemon) - it has the same problem. Edit inside container - watcher rebuilds. Edit outside the container - watcher does not rebuild.